# Python - update elements of a multidimensional dictionary

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I have the following info stored in a dict called "info1":

> [{'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'orderId': 480977, 'orderListId': -1, 'clientOrderId': 'S3', 'price': '0.00000000', 'origQty': '0.02000000', 'executedQty': '0.02000000', 'cummulativeQuoteQty': '25.07260000', 'status': 'FILLED', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'type': 'MARKET', 'side': 'BUY', 'stopPrice': '0.00000000', 'icebergQty': '0.00000000', 'time': 1672948804160, 'updateTime': 1672948804160, 'isWorking': True, 'workingTime': 1672948804160, 'origQuoteOrderQty': '0.00000000', 'selfTradePreventionMode': 'NONE'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'orderId': 566634, 'orderListId': -1, 'clientOrderId': 'S3', 'price': '0.00000000', 'origQty': '0.02000000', 'executedQty': '0.02000000', 'cummulativeQuoteQty': '24.98800000', 'status': 'FILLED', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'type': 'MARKET', 'side': 'SELL', 'stopPrice': '0.00000000', 'icebergQty': '0.00000000', 'time': 1672971274007, 'updateTime': 1672971274007, 'isWorking': True, 'workingTime': 1672971274007, 'origQuoteOrderQty': '0.00000000', 'selfTradePreventionMode': 'NONE'}]

How would I go about updating the values for both 'time' keys in this dict?

Have tried to identify the index of each, without luck.

Comment: Please add the code for your attempt and what is your expected output. What is the update you want to the time key?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you are not dealing with a dictionary, but a list of dictionaries.

```
isinstance(info1, list)

#True
```

That is why you can simply try to fetch a key and make an update here. First, you have to iterate through the list of dictionaries and then use `dict.update` to update specific key values. Here is how you can do this with a simple loop -

```
new_times = [1672948804190, 1672971274120] #one for each dict in list

for d,t in zip(info1, new_times):
  d.update({'time':t})

print(info1)
```

```
[{'symbol': 'ETHUSDT',
  'orderId': 480977,
  'orderListId': -1,
  'clientOrderId': 'S3',
  'price': '0.00000000',
  'origQty': '0.02000000',
  'executedQty': '0.02000000',
  'cummulativeQuoteQty': '25.07260000',
  'status': 'FILLED',
  'timeInForce': 'GTC',
  'type': 'MARKET',
  'side': 'BUY',
  'stopPrice': '0.00000000',
  'icebergQty': '0.00000000',
  'time': 1672948804190,                 #<---------
  'updateTime': 1672948804160,
  'isWorking': True,
  'workingTime': 1672948804160,
  'origQuoteOrderQty': '0.00000000',
  'selfTradePreventionMode': 'NONE'},
 {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT',
  'orderId': 566634,
  'orderListId': -1,
  'clientOrderId': 'S3',
  'price': '0.00000000',
  'origQty': '0.02000000',
  'executedQty': '0.02000000',
  'cummulativeQuoteQty': '24.98800000',
  'status': 'FILLED',
  'timeInForce': 'GTC',
  'type': 'MARKET',
  'side': 'SELL',
  'stopPrice': '0.00000000',
  'icebergQty': '0.00000000',
  'time': 1672971274120,                 #<---------
  'updateTime': 1672971274007,
  'isWorking': True,
  'workingTime': 1672971274007,
  'origQuoteOrderQty': '0.00000000',
  'selfTradePreventionMode': 'NONE'}]
```